# Selenium Error: invalid or illegal selector was specified. Even though the selector is valid

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find an element by its class name and click it with Selenium. When I run the code, I get the following error: `https://pastebin.com/1V2hHFGK`. I know that the element class name exists: `https://gyazo.com/ab0faa7f523a00a606b89d84215b9f87`. My code is below. If anyone can help fix this, that'd be great!

Code:

`https://pastebin.com/nfdqqV8k`

Comment: You need to post the code and error message as text, properly formatted, in your question not links to them. Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the HTML and properly format it instead.

Comment: `.link-2j8GS` is not a class name, it's a CSS selector for a class. `link-2j8GS` is a class name.

Answer (score 1):

You are using this :

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('.link-2j8GS')
```

which seems to be a dynamic class (may change during run time).

I think all you wanna do here is to get the `Sign up` text right ? If so, I see that it's between anchor tag (a).

I would suggest you to use `LINK_TEXT`, or `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`

```
find_element_by_link_text('Sign up').click()
```

or

```
find_element_by_partial_link_text('Sign up').click()
```

Comment: Now it just gives me the No Such Element error.

Comment: Can you check if it's in iframe ? I think it could be. Also I would like to see how are you using this solution in your code

Comment: How would I check if it's in iframe? This is how I'm using that solution in my code: https://pastebin.com/ai0bus02.

Comment: do you really need `click(Point(1208, 792))` ? I see there are 2 links `Twitter` and `Instagram` which one you want to click ?

Comment: I'm not trying to click either. That's to click the heart button.

Comment: Looks like that requires sign up for tiktok ,  sorry I can not sign up for that shitty app. Can you share HTML in the same way you have shared your code.

Comment: Here's the HTML on Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/WbKFhN3a @cruisepandey